# compass error while packaging

Tags: extjs

I generated a package as follows :
    sencha generate app GS e:\bhushan\GS7

After that I am trying to package a project using "sencha app build package native" command.

I am getting message as follows :
    [INF]           [shellscript] E:\bhushan\GS7\resources\sass>compass compile --bo
    ring --force
    [INF]           [shellscript] '''compass''' is not recognized as an internal or
    external comman

Do I need to install compass.
If yes, where can I find the installation and its steps to install on windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install compass, look at their website:
  - http://compass-style.org/install/

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking for windows 7 installation. The above site is for linux. Could you provide me one for windows.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  We can use gem on windows also. Installed successfully. Thank you.